# Cantor's ZigZag Function: Find the nth cell

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, iterator

Suppose I want to traverse a grid like in Cantor's proof of the countability of the rationals...

[image: Cantor ZigZag]

What's a function that takes an integer n and returns the row and column number for the nth cell in that traversal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a traversal there's no need for a closed form.

You can just use a sequence:

```
function*(grid){var r=0, c=0
    for(;;){yield grid[r][c]; c++; r--; if (r === -1) {r = c; c = 0}}
    }
```

Comment: Great point! I feel super silly that I dived straight into the rabbit hole of deriving the closed form without thinking about what actually makes sense from a programming perspective. :) But maybe both answers have some value. Thanks for posting this. Definitely recommended when what you really want is just the traversal. Nicely implemented, too!

Answer (score 1):

First we need the formula for the nth triangular number, as well as the inverse of that function:

```
t[n_] := n*(n+1)/2
ti[x_] := Floor[(Sqrt[8*x+1]-1)/2]
```

Then we can define Cantor's ZigZag like so:

```
zig[n_] := Module[{y = n-1-t[ti[n-1]]}, 
  {ti[n-1]-y, y} + 1]
```

(I wrote and tested this in Mathematica but it's just arithmetic so will look about the same in any language.)

Comment: Improvements thanks to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function which I just discovered!